# Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add subititle under the video while video play. And I used firebase to store my data in the project. I have implemented a lot since I started the project, so it was a bit confusing. So I am getting some errors.

**My errors**

```
Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable


Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice found in modules jetified-proto-google-common-protos-2.8.3 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.8.3) and jetified-protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)


Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction


Caused by: com.android.builder.merge.DuplicateRelativeFileException: 5 files found with path 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST' from inputs:


Caused by: com.android.builder.merge.DuplicateRelativeFileException: 5 files found with path 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'.
```

**build.gradle(:app)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
   
}


android {
    compileSdk 31



    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.talhakara.uzaktanegitimbitirmeprojesi"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
    }
}




def multidex_version = "2.0.1"

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:17.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    implementation files('libs\\jmxri-1.2.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs\\jmxtools-1.2.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs\\jmxri-1.2.1.jar')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:17.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.0.0'


    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'


    implementation ('org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:2.9.0') { transitive = true }


    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')


    //google cloud speech recognition
   //implementation platform('com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:25.4.0')
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-speech'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-speech:2.3.0'
//    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.46.0'
//    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-speech:2.3.0-alpha'

    //
    //implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"
   /* implementation('log4j:log4j:1.2.15') {
        exclude group: 'javax.jms', module: 'jms'
    }*/
}
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
#Tue Jun 14 14:42:54 TRT 2022
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

**setting.gradle**

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        maven {
            url "https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases"
        }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "UzaktanEgitimBitirmeProjesi"
include ':app'
```

**gradle.properties**

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app"s APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true
```

**build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()//  mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I am getting duplicate class error also. I tried to solve this problem as much as I could, so I commented the dependcys that I thought were duplicates in build.gradle, but I still get an error. what could be the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Try to change your **build.gradle(:app)**.

Replace:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

with

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: it doesnt work unfortunately. do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Aren't they both the same thing?

Comment: I keep getting the same errors nothing has changed